# Using bash script with read and return statement

Tags: bash, echo, return-value

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Example script for validating SVN credentials.

var_svn_user_name=
var_svn_password=

function get_svn_credentials()
{
  # First, get the credentials from the user
  read -r -p "Please enter SVN User Name: " var_svn_user_name
  echo -n "Please enter SVN Password:  "
  read -r -s var_svn_password
  echo ""
  echo "----------------"
  echo "The SVN User Name is:     ${var_svn_user_name}"
  echo "The SVN User Password is: ${var_svn_password}"

  # Next, validate provided credentials
  echo -n "Validating credentials... "
  #var_ret=$(svn list --username "${var_svn_user_name}" --password \
  #        "${var_svn_password}" ${var_url} ${var_cfg} ${var_opt}=${var_val} \
  #        --no-auth-cache --non-interactive 2>&1 | grep "Authentication failed")
  if [[ $var_ret == "" ]]
  then
    echo 'Success'
  else
    echo 'Failed'
  fi
}

function main()
{
  # EXAMPLE Call #1
  #result=$(get_svn_credentials)  # FAILURE
  # EXAMPLE Call #2
  get_svn_credentials           # SUCCESS

  echo "Return value is: $result"
  if [[ $var_ret == "Success" ]]
  then
    echo "SVN User Name and Password was validated."
  else
    echo "SVN User Name and Password was NOT validated."
  fi
}

main "$@"
```

Why is it that when I comment out Example 2 and uncomment Example 1, the echoing of password does not get displayed until read executes?

I am trying to figure out how to get the return statement to work like a C function style return statement.

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: What `return` statement are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing your prompt to standard output, which is captured by the command substitution. Write it to standard error instead (like `read -p` does).

```
function get_svn_credentials()
{
  # First, get the credentials from the user
  read -r -p "Please enter SVN User Name: " var_svn_user_name
  echo -n "Please enter SVN Password:  " >&2
  read -r -s var_svn_password

  {
    echo ""
    echo "----------------"
    echo "The SVN User Name is:     ${var_svn_user_name}"
    echo "The SVN User Password is: ${var_svn_password}"
  } >&2

  # Next, validate provided credentials
  echo -n "Validating credentials... "
  #var_ret=$(svn list --username "${var_svn_user_name}" --password \
  #        "${var_svn_password}" ${var_url} ${var_cfg} ${var_opt}=${var_val} \
  #        --no-auth-cache --non-interactive 2>&1 | grep "Authentication failed")
  if [[ $var_ret == "" ]]
  then
    echo 'Success'
  else
    echo 'Failed'
  fi
}
```

That said, don't rely on the output to determine if it succeeded or not; just use the exit status.

```
get_svn_credentials () {
  local user_name password
  # First, get the credentials from the user
  read -r -p "Please enter SVN User Name: " user_name
  read -r -p "Please enter SVN Password:  " -s password

  {
    echo ""
    echo "----------------"
    echo "The SVN User Name is:     ${user_name}"
    echo "The SVN User Password is: ${password}"
  } >&2

  # Next, validate provided credentials
  # Let the exit status of grep -q be the exit status
  # of the function
  printf '%s\n' "Validating credentials... " >&2
  svn list --username "${user_name}" \
           --password "${password}" \
           "${var_url}" ${var_cfg} "${var_opt}=${var_val}" \
          --no-auth-cache --non-interactive 2>&1 |
    grep -q "Authentication failed"
}

main () {
  if get_svn_credentials
  then
    echo "SVN User Name and Password was validated."
  else
    echo "SVN User Name and Password was NOT validated."
  fi
}

main
```

(Note: you should *probably* be quoting `$var_cfg`, but it's possible it is actually a list of options. In that case, you should be using an array instead, but as it's impossible to tell from this code alone, I've left it unquoted.)

Comment: Thank you this looks great.  The curly braces with echo block made the script continue to display "Please enter SVN Password" when I uncommented "EXAMPLE Call 1" in my original post.

I wonder if there is is defacto book about scripting and styling, the bash script is so flexible it is hard to understand what it is doing sometimes.

Comment: The curly braces just define a command block, so I could redirect the output of all for `echo` commands to standard error (with `>&2`) at once instead of redirecting each of the four separately.